Creating a chrome extension that logs a timer on tab, how can I keep the tab active if I switch tabs purely from background.js? (prevent throttling)
I can't manipulate DOM elements and can't make changes to content.js file.
Purely need to prevent throttling from a service worker.js file.
Tried using chrome storage
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((tabInfo) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
        if (tab.url == "123.com/") {
            chrome.storage.session.set({ targetActivated: tab.id });
            console.log(tab);
        } else {
            chrome.storage.session.get("targetActivated", (data) => {
                const targetTabId = data.targetActivated;
                if (targetTabId) {
                    chrome.tabs.update(targetTabId, { active: true });
                    console.log(targetTabId)
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});

I tried getting the tab info and tab state when its active and use storage to swap the state of the inactive tab with the state from when it was active.
tried using chrome tabs and url
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((tabInfo) => {
        chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
            if (tab.url === "123.com/") {
                console.log(tab);
                return;
            } else {
                chrome.tabs.query({ url: "123.com/" }, (tabs_list) => {
                    if (tabs_list.length > 0) {
                        chrome.tabs.update(tabs_list[0].id, { active: true });
                    }   
                    console.log(tabs_list[0])        
                });
            }
        });
});


check the open tabs on chrome window and adjust active property to true.
Also tried manipulating all the page events to do nothing and it still doesn't prevent throttling from purely the serviceworker.js file. Any ideas?

Use setInterval inside the service worker, send a message to the tab id in the callback, the content script's onMessage will print to console. You'll also need to keep the service worker alive.

@wOxxOm is the keepng the service worker alive using this?  function connect() {   chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'keepAlive'})     .onDisconnect.addListener(connect); }

See the link in my comment.

@wOxxOm is there a way to do it purely from background.js with no updates to the content.js script?

It depends on what's inside the content script.

@wOxxOm just a timer that logs each second....but it stops logging if the tab becomes inactive and throttling occurs. My goal was to use serviceworker.js to keep it running and not detect if I left tab / or keep tab active while on a different tab.

Why is this a requirement: "with no updates to the content.js script"? It's really weird.
